# File path for base64 image in Android

Tags: android, path, base64

In the app I am making, I would like to take a Base64 image that is received from a server, and save it to a file for displaying later. My question is where should I store this file? It needs to be dynamic, and may be empty when the program launches. I am unsure how exactly the file system on Android works, such as how file paths look.

Ideally I would like to be able to write the data to the image file using a FileOutputStream, and then display that image somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should follow the standards defined on the [Android Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) docs. This will give you information on how to save to internal storage, external storage (sdcard for example), and to a database.

Since you are "caching" the file, you would save it to the selected storage (internal/external) to `/Android/data/<package_name>/cache/`. You would probably only want to use internal storage if external storage was not available, in my opinion.